# Add incremental number by matching the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Below is my SQL Server 2012 query example. How do I add an extra column “StaffNo” to show an incremental integer?

1. This int always starts with 1, it doesn’t need to be matching with the staff name. for example “Joe” in this query running shows 1 in staff No, in next query running he could be 2 or 3 or any other number.
2. Same user always appear same staff No. Different user appear different No.
3. The number must be sequential and the increment is 1.
4. Because Staff is more than 100, so don’t write the query like “select case when staff = ‘Joe’ then 1 End”.

my query:

```
Staff    CaseNumber
Joe      5880       
Joe      4489
Joe      2235
Emily   7790
Emily   8813
```

expected result:

```
Staff    CaseNumber    StaffNo
Joe      5880               1
Joe      4489               1
Joe      2235               1
Emily   7790               2
Emily   8813               2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` over the entire table, without a partiton, and order by the staff member's name.

```
SELECT
    Staff,
    CaseNumber,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Staff) StaffNo
FROM yourTable;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: StaffNo doesn't exist, and I want to create it. you can't select StaffNo in query.

Comment: @paddywide Sorry I just tested my query and made a few minor changes.  It is working now.

Comment: Will different staff appear same staff no? it seems dense_rank allow this happen.

Comment: Each unique staff name will have a unique dense rank.  If two or more separate people have the same staff name in your table, then you should add another column  to distinguish them.